# Varias conexões usando um socket

Tags: c#, socket, tcp, tcpclient

Tenho uma conexão *socket* que funciona bem com TCP/UDP, o problema é que uso `Tcp1.Connect` e ele barra mais de uma conexão. Em uma pesquisa na internet verifiquei que o certo seria usar o `Tcp1.BeginConnect` que possibilita usar mais de uma *thread*.

No meu cenário tenho `foreach` que percorre as linhas do *Grid* pegando o **ip** e **porta do equipamento**. Minha dúvida é como montar várias *threads*, ou então como usar a conexão assincrônica  dentro deste *loop*.

Alguém teria algum exemplo?

O código que estou usando para enviar mensagem para o equipamento:

```
  TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient();
   UdpClient udp1 = new UdpClient();

    #region Menssagem Rápida
    private void cmd_msg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string command = "";
        string preCommand = "";
        byte chkSum = 0;

        Random rnd = new Random();

        chaveAes[0] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[1] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[2] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[3] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[4] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[5] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[6] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[7] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[8] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[9] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[10] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[11] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[12] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[13] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[14] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));
        chaveAes[15] = Convert.ToByte(rnd.Next(1, 256));

        string comandoCatraca = "01+REON+00+20]5]" + mensagem_rapida + "]";
        command = "";
        command = command + (char)(2);

        preCommand = preCommand + (char)((comandoCatraca).ToString().Length);
        preCommand = preCommand + (char)(0);
        preCommand = preCommand + comandoCatraca;
        chkSum = calcCheckSumString(preCommand);

        command = command + preCommand;
        command = command + Convert.ToChar(chkSum);
        command = command + (char)(3);

        byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);

        tcp1.Client.Send(array);
    }
    #endregion
```

Alguém sabe como consigo receber os dados dos equipamentos neste método a baixo passado pelo nosso amigo Rick.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: [Aqui](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm) você encontra um bom exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Tem esse exemplo, você pode abrir diversos clientes e testar como o código trabalha

Servidor:

```
class Program
  {
static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0], 11000);
    Console.WriteLine("Local address and port : {0}", localEP.ToString());

    Socket listener = new Socket(localEP.Address.AddressFamily,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEP);
        listener.Listen(10);

        while (true)
        {
            allDone.Reset();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener);

            allDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Closing the listener...");
}

static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    allDone.Set();

    // Create the state object.
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.WorkSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket.
    int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    // Data was read from the client socket.
    if (read > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] read {1} bytes", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, read);
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, read));
        handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }
    else
    {
        if (state.sb.Length > 1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the client;
            // display it on the console.
            string content = state.sb.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Read {1} bytes from socket.\n Data : {2}",
               Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, content.Length, content);
        }
        handler.Close();
    }
}

public class StateObject
{
    public Socket WorkSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

}

Client:

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipHostInfo.AddressList[0], 11000);

    Socket s = new Socket(remoteEP.Address.AddressFamily,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.Connect(remoteEP);

    Console.WriteLine("Connected, sending a few bytes...");
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello");
    s.Send(bytes);

    Console.Write("Now press ENTER to send remaining bytes...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" world");
    s.Send(bytes);

    s.Close();
    s.Dispose();
}}
```

Comment: Não entendi aonde passa o ip para conexão

Comment: Você diz no cliente ou no servidor?

Comment: Procura a linha do IPEndPoint

Exemplo:
string serverIP = "192.168.0.1";
string port = 8000;
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), port);

Comment: No servidor mesmo, preciso usar essa parte do cliente também ?

Comment: Precisa colocar nos dois

Comment: Conseguir passar o ip com a porta, mas da um erro no `listener.Bind(localEP);` fala que o endereço não é valido no contexto, esta parte do cliente pra que server?

Comment: O ip que fica no cliente é o ip que ele vai se conectar, o server e o client precisa está na mesma porta

Comment: exemplo muito bom!

Comment: Eu tenho uma outra duvida, tenho outros métodos que usa `tcp1.Client.Send(array);` para enviar massagens para o equipamento, como posso instanciar este exemplo, para usar em outras parte do meu código?

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar uma parte desse código?

Comment: Posso sim, eu vou editar a minha pergunta e vou colocar lá pode ser!?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como instanciar o `tcp1.Send(bytes);` pra mim usar em outras parte do código. Colocar ele como Global